# Capture the Keyword FAILED from a file and send out a email notification

Tags: email, powershell

I require a PowerShell script to capture the error FAILED from an output file and, if the status is FAILED, then send the email to the DL list with the subject as failed and in the body of the email should have output file format as it is. I am stuck in writing the `if` statement. Please help me.

The location of the output file is D:\logs.

Format of the output file:

```
process_id       : 1
STATUS           : FAILED
RULE_ID          : 44
RULE_NAME        : OEBS-1
LAST_UPDATE_DATE : 1/4/2017 11:37:02 AM
```

Comment: You need to parse the information out of your output file. What have you tried so far? What does your code currently look like? Where does it fail (exactly)? We're willing to help, but SO is not a place where we do your work for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
import-csv d:\logs\logfile.csv | where-object { $_.STATUS -eq "FAILED" } | 
send-mailmessage -from "User01 <user01@example.com>" -to "User02 <user02@example.com>",
"User03 <user03@example.com>" -subject "Sending the Attachment" -body     
"Forgot to send the attachment. Sending now." -Attachments "data.csv" 
-priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -smtpServer smtp.fabrikam.com
```

I have used the send-mailmessage from Example 2 of here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. This gives the examples of using many of the send-mailmessage paramaters. You can use the ones you require, or modify to add what you would like.

** The formatting of the code might be out. I tried to keep it reasonably tidy and on one page without scrolling. I haven't used ` to indicate a new line as you would in actual PowerShell code.

```
$failed = import-csv d:\logs\logfile.csv | where-object {$_.STATUS -eq "FAILED"}
send-mailmessage -from failedjob@fabrikam.com -to dl@fabrikam.com -subject Failed -body $failed -smtpserver mailserverthatwillaccept.fabrikam.com
```

That's another option.

** Edited to import-csv as per comments from Ansgar

Thanks, Tim.

Comment: `Get-Content` returns an array of strings. Strings do not have a property `STATUS`, so you'd never get any matches.

Comment: What makes you believe the file were in CSV format? Nothing in the question would suggest that.

Comment: It may help OP understand how the commands work. If it were or could be in CSV, then the answer presented would work. Thanks for the heads up on get-content, that was a mistake on my part. Hopefully my answer will help OP see what can be done. If not, I'm happy to delete my answer. Thanks, Tim.

Comment: The output text file have the  below format                                        process_id       : 1
STATUS           : FAILED
RULE_ID          : 44
RULE_NAME        : OEBS-1
LAST_UPDATE_DATE : 1/4/2017 11:37:02 AM                                                      Iam looking for a condition if the status = FAILED ,then check the get content of the file and spool out the msg to the dl list with the subject as  failed and the body of the email should be same as the output text file. Please help me in writing the conditions

Comment: Is it one text file with all the job information in it or is a text file created per job?